# Performance difference when a binary is compiled on two different linux distros

Tags: linux, performance, gcc, portability, portable-executable

I have implemented a user space FUSE filesystem.
The fuse filesystem is running on a SUSE machine with kernel version 3.12 and I use the fio benchmark to test the write throughput.
By default the write speed is 650 MB/sec.
When I compile the same source code and generate filesystem binary on a UBUNTU machine, scp it to SUSE machine and measure performance, it drops by almost 50%. The Ubuntu machine is also running on same kernel version.
Both machines have same 64 bit arch.

However the gcc version is different:
On ubuntu it is gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
On Suse it is gcc version 4.4.7 20120313

I guess this might make some difference, but almost 50% performance is huge. What could be the possible reasons and possible way(s) to avoid it?

EDIT1:
To be more clear, there are 2 machines with exactly the same hardware configuration. Ubuntu (machine A) and Suse (machine B)
The binaries are compiled on different machines but executed on same machine (Suse machine B) so the run environment is exactly similar for both binaries.

Comment: Sounds like a difference in hardware, you didn't mention anything about available RAM, what type of hard drives, CPU's ...

Comment: I have updated the question to make it more clear. As the performance is measured on same machine all the factors are exactly same